# How to migrate a web site to Zurb Foundation 6 from Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am looking a at large project that used Foundation version 4.x . This project has used the grid extensively: almost all HTML pages have

css classes from version 4x such as

```
row, large-12 columns, panel, callout
```

I am trying to figure out a few basic methods to transition ?

question :are row, columns and panel classes still supported ?

how to translate old row and column to new grid classes i.e. if I have a

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="large-12 columns">
```

what is the equivalent in Foundation 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Flex Grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html) or [Float Grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html) is supported still, however you need to import Foundation slightly differently.

### To use the Float Grid in Foundation v6.4+, you need to:

In CDN link or package managers: import `foundation-float.css` in place of `foundation.css`.

In Sass: set both `$xy-grid` and `$global-flexbox` to `false`.

### To use the Flex Grid in Foundation v6.4+, you need to:

In CDN link or package managers: import `foundation-flex.css` in place of `foundation.css`.

In Sass: set `$xy-grid` to `false`.

### To update your HTML to use the XY Grid

Based on the example you have given, the most direct 'conversion' would be:

```
<div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell">
```

[You can learn more about the XY Grid system here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html)